# Merged question doesn't show as "closed"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, merged-questions

Merged questions don't have "[Closed]" in their titles. Shouldn't they?

Example: https://superuser.com/questions/218279/windows-7-ultimate-features-on-or-off-dialog-box-is-empty

Comment: Here a fresh example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570289/create-oracle-cursor

Comment: I wish I could upvote the above myself. Closing merged questions really needs to be done.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the post isn't actually closed -- it's locked. See the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/218279/revisions).

It essentially becomes the same as the stub left behind in a migrated question, so I think the question that really needs to be asked is: do merged questions need to be closed and locked instead of just locked?

Comment: They should be, since the original question still counts as "unanswered" if it's not closed. Probably merging should just auto-close as a duplicate of the merge target

Answer (score 3):

I agree this is confusing. The merge text itself states "this question was merged with XYZ because it is **an exact duplicate of that question**".

So it makes sense for the behavior of a merge to also close the question as a duplicate, rather than simply lock it.

**Update:**

> [We will only allow merge to happen if one of the questions being merged is currently closed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101667/example-newsletter-shows-a-merged-closed-question/102189#102189)