# Merged question displayed on 10k "Most close votes" report

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, 10k-tools, merged-questions, close-list

Merged questions that cannot be closed are displayed in the 10k close report if they have a sufficient number of close votes against them. This feels wrong, since there's nothing we can/should do (I think) with these questions.

[Here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417999/source-code-for-reading-int32bit-dataset-integervalues-saparated-by-extra-crlf-in):

[image]

But in the question:
[image]

Related: [Merged question doesn't show as “closed”.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71488/merged-question-doesnt-show-as-closed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed; merged posts don't really belong there. They'll be excluded from those displays when a build happens.