# Why aren't merged answers tagged in their titles?

Tags: support, merged-questions

I came across this question which was recently merged: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551090/codegolf-find-the-unique-paths

It's *not* marked as closed in the title and as such there is no indication from seeing it in a list of questions why it has 0 votes and 0 answers (for reference the [main copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551054/codegolf-find-the-unique-paths) has 11 votes and 8 answers). Is this a bug, missing feature or by design?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71488/merged-question-doesnt-show-as-closed/71489#71489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not closed. It's *locked*.* And locked questions don't get anything appended to their titles.

*<sub>Ok, so this isn't obvious either... Merge-source questions are automatically locked - it's implicit in the "merged" indicator following the question, and explicitly noted in [the question's revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4551090/revisions).</sub>

Comment: Then the question is, should they get `[locked]` appended to their titles?

Comment: @marcog: can you think of a good reason? If so, post that as a feature request.

Comment: @Shog I gave one in my question: while browsing for questions I come across this question with 0 votes/answers and it triggers me to look into it, when it's just wasting my time. It servers the same purpose as `[closed]` IMHO.

Comment: @Shog Are you saying the right thing is to open a *new* request?

Comment: @marcog: yes, that's what I'm saying. You understand what's happening now, so you can make an informed suggestion that it change.

Comment: @Shog Sure, just didn't want to be unnecessarily spammy. Was thinking editing the current question was more acceptable. Posted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73519/mark-locked-questions-locked-in-their-titles).

Comment: @marcog: well, my theory is that if *you* had to ask this question then chances are someone else will wonder the same thing - and now they'll have a ready answer.

Answer (score 0):

This one should have been deleted anyway, so your question is moot.

I've deleted it.

Comment: Is this true for all merges? Seems it might not be the case according to [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16437/when-merging-questions-leave-the-duplicate-one-as-a-placeholder).