# Example newsletter shows a merged (closed) question

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter

I was just playing with our site's [example newsletter](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=sharepoint.stackexchange.com) and found it [contained a link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17309/getting-started-with-sharepoint-2010) to a merged (and therefore 'closed') question under the "Can you answer these?" title. It doesn't make sense for this type of question to show there.

[image: Newsletter]

The question was merged almost 24 hours ago so I don't think this is a caching issue.

Could someone please check?

Comment: if the question is not closed, this means new answers can arrive. That's.. not good.. for a merged question.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I now understand the behaviour, but why aren't merged questions [automatically closed as exact dupes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71488/merged-question-doesnt-show-as-closed/101801#101801)? It's confusing...

Comment: Merging locks them, so they can't actually get new answers, but other parts of the system check close state, so it really should [auto-close upon merge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71488/merged-question-doesnt-show-as-closed#comment-172253)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will only allow merge to happen if one of the questions being merged is currently closed.

Comment: Is there a technical reason why merging can't just close as a duplicate first?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas I don't understand this line of reasoning - merging just become more painful with this - refer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102444/merging-questions-is-kinda-sorta-broken for my problem