# Merging questions is kinda sorta broken

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, merged-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closed-then-merged question missing "closed by" and "merged to" footers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53322/closed-then-merged-question-missing-closed-by-and-merged-to-footers)

SO, there's this question which [was migrated from](https://superuser.com/questions/322970/is-it-possible-to-auto-run-an-extension-for-all-new-chrome-windows-created) Stack Overflow. The same was reposted by the [OP on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/322872/is-it-possible-to-auto-run-an-extension-for-all-new-chrome-windows-created). At first attempt, I tried to merge it - that's generally what I try to do. But, I hit a roadblock with this error message:

> At least one of the questions for the merge must be closed

(Wait, Why should one of the questions be closed?)

OOOK. So I closed the migrated question as dupe of the reposted one and then tried to merge. Doing so, the stub about post being merged into the other is totally missing.

[image: Y U NO MERGE!?]

So, attempted to try it again, by reopening. *Now* it says the question is merged :/

[image: Merged :/]

So to merge - I have to close a question, merge it, reopen it, and then edit out the possible duplicate stub? Why? Can we please have the old-plain-merge functionality back?

Comment: Why merge when there are no answers to the migrated question?

Comment: There was an answer @CodyGray, the questions are now merged.

Comment: Right, your answer. I assumed you answered the one on SU, not the one on SO. Maybe that was an invalid assumption.

Comment: @CodyGray No, your assumption was correct. It was migrated from SO, I posted the answer. Later, he reposted it on SU. I hadn't noticed that he had reposted it on SU while answering the migrated question.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101667/example-newsletter-shows-a-merged-closed-question/102189#102189 - this change was done because questions that *aren't* closed are not treated as closed questions by the system. Some crazy folks thought the solution was for merging to automatically close the question, but those folks were crazy - the proper response is for you to close the question and then merge it. Also, migration breaks everything.

Comment: @Random - This isn't about the merge footer being missing. This is about the merge not happening w/o a question being closed.

Comment: Merging only being allowed if one is closed is the new behaviour fix though, close as the newsletter one?

Comment: yeah I'm not happy with the new behaviour - I've left a comment on the newsletter question