# How to exclude merged questions from searches

Tags: support, merged-questions

I am trying to search for questions that:

- Have no answers at all (so the Unanswered Questions tab doesn't do what I want, as it shows questions with no *Accepted* answer)
- Have been upvoted, so there are people interested in the question
- The system will allow to be answered

A Stack Overflow search for ['answers:0 closed:0 votes:10'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers:0%20closed:0%20votes:10&submit=search) seemed promising, and currently gives 15 hits.

However, almost all of them contain "this question was merged with..."

How can I adjust the above query to exclude questions that have been merged with other questions?

Notes:

- I have read the [Search Options page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=), and am aware of how to search for *closed* and *migrated* questions: this is specifically about merged ones.)
- I've also tried searching for [body:"this question was merged with"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3A%22this+question+was+merged+with%22). Not surprisingly, this didn't find the kinds of questions I'm wanting to exclude, as I presume that the "this question was merged with..." text is added programatically.
- I've seen this [Merged questions still show up in the Unanswered list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66068/merged-questions-still-show-up-in-the-unanswered-list), which is great, but I'm not searching the Unanswered page. If I knew how to combine the "Unanswered" page with `answers:0 closed:0 votes:10` it would probably do the trick.

**Edit**

It's actually [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers:0%20closed:0%20votes:10) that I'm trying to emulate - the search terms are the same as my link above, but the "newest" page is selected, allowing the newest popular, unanswered questions to be viewed first.

**Edit 2**

I just added a [separate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108839/169815), suggesting a new advanced search facility: `merged:0` (and its counterpart `merged:1`)

Comment: Doesn't the [no answers tab](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) do what you want?

Comment: @ChrisF: Thanks, I didn't know it existed. I've tried it out, and it doesn't really help much, as it sorts by votes, so the stuff at the top can be quite old. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct procedure for a moderator to merge a question is

1. Close as "Exact duplicate" of target question
2. Merge answers with those of target question

You can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662/must-see-tech-talks-presentations) that step 1 was never performed and hence the question is still counted as "open". Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949818/how-can-i-learn-android) of a question that was closed first and *then* merged.

So if it was never closed, searching with `closed:0` will not prevent them from showing up on the list. To be fair to the moderators who merged the questions in your list, the system did not require them to close the question first. This has now been changed and is enforced by the software. This recent change [was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101667/example-newsletter-shows-a-merged-closed-question/102189#102189) because merged questions kept showing up in the newsletter.

So all questions that were merged without closing prior to this change will appear in your searches. Since merges cannot be undone, I'm afraid you'll have to look through the list yourself. However, since it's only 14 questions in your query, it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: Thanks very much. In practice, I'd be searching for a lower number of votes, so would have a rather larger number of hits to sift through. Is there really no way to search for _merged_ questions, then, as it's a different concept from _closed_?

Comment: Thanks, but sorry if I wasn't clear: I understand that they are different concepts, and why: I just don't understand why it seems impossible to search specifically for (stubs of) merged questions.

Comment: @ClareMacrae Oh, I misread what you were asking :D. The answer is no, you can't search for it, because the functionality has not been provided. There probably aren't too many cases where people would want to search for merged posts specifically (why would they, because nothing can be done to it), which is why they haven't added it. You can't search for locked posts either and the ability to search for deleted posts is available only to the moderators.

Comment: OK, thanks. (I didn't spell it out, but my reasoning for ability to search for merged posts would be to _exclude_ them: I was presuming that if `merged:1` was provided, then there would be the related `merged:0`. There do seem to be a fair number of merged-but-not-closed posts - I guess we will just have to live with them. Thanks again for the answer.)