# Should this merged question also be marked as closed?

Tags: discussion

Should questions like this be marked as closed?

[What's the reason for my ASP.NET Cache never expiring, despite having a sliding expiration time set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337897/whats-the-reason-for-my-asp-net-cache-never-expiring-despite-having-a-sliding)

It is my understanding that merged questions (that had answers stripped) should be marked as closed, based upon this meta post:

[Merged question doesn't show as "closed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71488/merged-question-doesnt-show-as-closed)

Comment: **No**, Those already shows merged and that is understood IMHO

Comment: I understand the opinion, it just seems counter to the status-completed feature-request. Am I missing something?